# How to load an image from JSON response?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, image

I am using the below code to load an image from json response and display the image in `UICollectionView`. But the `numberofItems` in Section count does return 0 . It means `imageArray2.count` returns 0. It does not work. Can anybody tell me  where I am doing wrong in the below code? `imageArray2` is my `NSArray`.

// JSON RESPONSE

```
claimImages =     (
                {
            "image_url" = "http://zapponomics.net/claimservice/parcelimage/555506520image0.jpg";
            "img_for" = "Front view of parcel";
            "pro_number" = Rita;
        }
    );
    images =     (
                {
            "image_url" = "http://zapponomics.net/claimservice/parcelimage/384270647image0.jpg";
            "img_for" = "Front view of parcel";
            "pro_number" = Rita;
        }
    );
 NSMutableDictionary *imageDict2 = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"claimImages"];
                NSLog(@"Image Dictionary :- %@",imageDict2);
                imageArray2 = [imageDict2 valueForKey:@"image_url"];
                NSLog(@"My Array Image :- %@",imageArray2);

    -(void)loadImageFromURL2:(NSURL *) url callback:(void(^)(UIImage *image1))callback
    {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSData *imageData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
                callback(image1);
            });
        });
    }
     if (collectionView.tag == 601)
        {
            cell = [afterParcelCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            UIImageView *myImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 80)];
            myImageView2.tag = 102;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView2];

            NSString *myImage1= [imageArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self loadImageFromURL2:[NSURL URLWithString:[myImage1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]] callback:^(UIImage *image1){

                myImageView2.image =image1;
            }];
        }

              return cell;
```

Comment: please post your `jsonDict` here

Comment: claimImages =     (
                {
            "image_url" = "http://zapponomics.net/claimservice/parcelimage/555506520image0.jpg";
            "img_for" = "Front view of parcel";
            "pro_number" = Rita;
        }
    );

Comment: `[jsonDict valueForKey:@"claimImages"]` is an array but you are adding it to a `NSMutableDictionary`. Also, please add your json in the question (edit it) in legible formatting.

Comment: U Can now check my updated question post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and replace your code:

```
NSArray *claimImagesArray = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"claimImages"];
NSLog(@"%@", claimImagesArray);


NSString *imagePath = [[claimImagesArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"image_url"];
NSLog(@"My Image :- %@", imagePath);
```

Comment: THIS CODE will generate two images automatically.